Random search for hyper-parameter tuning on Yolov8
I am a beginner on deep learning models development. I would like to implement a object detection model using Yolov8 and I want to use random search hyper-parameters tuning to improve my model performance, can someone help me with a model sample of random search hyper-parameter tuning for a yolov8 object detection model?
Thank you.
I saw that on yolo there is a tune() function, but i would like to use random search.
https://docs.ultralytics.com/guides/hyperparameter-tuning/#what-are-hyperparameters
